# Regex test function do not return the same depending quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a weird case with a regular expression in javascript:

```
var re = /[^\s]+(?:\s+|$)/g;
re.test('foo'); // return true
re.test("foo"); // return false
```

Is a regular expression type sensitive? My first goal is to extract all word (separated by one or more whitespace) of a string.

Thanks for your help.

Julien

Comment: What do you mean by 'type sensitive'?

Comment: If you keep running `re.test('foo');`, it alternates between `true` and `false`. This is pretty strange.

Comment: You are right Blender. Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behavior of Javascript regex test function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331753/strange-behavior-of-javascript-regex-test-function)

Comment: Just a tiny bit more testing, and you would have seen that it has nothing to do with the quotes.

Comment: yes, you right. Everthing is in the F.J. answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using the `g` flag on a Javascript regular expression, it will keep track of where the last match was found and start searching from that index the next time you try to find a match.

Between the two `re.test()` calls, take a look at `re.lastIndex` to see what I am talking about.

For example:

```
var re = /[^\s]+(?:\s+|$)/g;
re.test('foo'); // return true
re.lastIndex;   // 3
re.test("foo"); // return false
```

You will notice that the type of quotes you use does not matter, `re.test('foo'); re.test('foo');` will have the same behavior.

If you want the regex to start fresh, you can either remove the global flag from your regex or set `re.lastIndex` to `0` after each attempt to find a match, for example:

```
var re = /[^\s]+(?:\s+|$)/g;
re.test('foo'); // return true
re.lastIndex = 0;
re.test("foo"); // return true
```

The alternating noted by Blender in comments can be explained because `lastIndex` is automatically set to `0` when a match fails, so the next attempt after the failure will succeed.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I cannot remove global parameter because i have to handle string like "foo bar ". You solution looks to work. Thank you very much.